# Is it possible to use Java 1.3 with WAS 8.5?

Tags: websphere

WAS 8.5 supports Java 1.6. I want to use Java 1.3 with WAS 8.5. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you must use the version(s) of Java that is bundled with the product.